# Changing PlotStyle while mapping ListLinePlot at several datasets

Tags: plotting, map

Assume that I have several datasets in a matrix and I want to plot them using

```
Show[
 ListLinePlot[#,
    PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}] & /@

  Table[Transpose[{RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, 10], 
     RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, 10]}], {i, 2}],
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

Obviously, this doesn't work as both datasets are shown in blue. How can I plot them in different colors?

Comment: Use `ListLinePlot[{list1, list2}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]` or `ListLinePlot[{Style[list1, Red], Style[list2, Blue]}]`.

Comment: HAHA! that was easy, thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 2):

use `@` instead of `/@`

```
ListLinePlot[#, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}] &@
 Table[Transpose[{RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, 10], 
    RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, 10]}], {i, 2}]
```